# How to get the user input using textfield from Apple watch

Tags: ios, iphone, watchkit, apple-watch

I want to design a password screen for my Apple Watch app. `UITextField` is not supported by `WKInterface`. How do I design such a screen? Are any APIs or customizations available?

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't a good way to input a password from apple watch. Apple doesn't want you to do this, so even if you find a way to do it, I would bet apple would reject your app. Also take into account that the apple watch locks every time it is removed from your wrist, so you have to type in a password to use your application anyway. However, if you still want to input a password from apple watch, I would suggest building it yourself. Just use the digital crown to flip through the alphabet and add the character to a password string once the user taps it.

Comment: Thank u for ur valuable reply,But if you see HDFC iWatch Application from watch app store the password screen is there.Every time you want do the transactions need to enter the Password.SO that I thought there is a feasibility.If u have time just see that app

Comment: @SankaraLakshmanan I looked at the app, but I didn't see a password screen

Answer (score 0):

You can try to build a calculator like keyboard with groups and buttons.

Answer (score 0):

The closest equivalent to iOS's `UITextField` is the text input method presented in WatchKit using [presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions:allowedInputMode:completion:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions:allowedInputMode:completion:)

This would seem like a pretty poor way to input a traditional password, given the vagaries of dictation, though you could think about this more flexibly. For instance, what if the required 'password' was to dictate a phrase that included at least three words out of four words that had been pre-set as the passphrase. That would have a fair degree of entropy, but account reasonably for the likelihood that at times one of the dictated words might be mis-recognised by the API.